# Unity doesn't load

Tags: unity, hdmi, amd-graphics

Before this, all was alright then I was installing `ATI/AMD` drivers to have HDMI sound in my TV, all was installing fine but then I restart my computer and `Unity` was gone: menu, bar, and all that things where gone. I don´t know what to do to make it work again. I have tried the classic solution:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

and then appears:

```
(dconf:3470): GLib-WARNING **:(/bulid/bulid/glib2.0-2.36.0/./glib/gerror.c:390):g_error_new_valist:runtime check failed: (domain !=0)
error: dconf path must begin with slash ...
```

I try to enable Unity with CcSM but it says that OpenGl is needed and can´t enable it.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try this `aticonfig --uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem when i installed the nvidea driver on my notbook after installing a new kernel version. Unity did not load, i were stuck with the command line. I removed the graphic driver and used the generic drivers to boot to a desktop again. I fixed it by checking the kernel version and installing a new graphic driver.

Check that you have installed the right grafik driver for your kernel.